# Php data decryption

Tags: php

I have encrypted data in PHP database. Data is encrypted using AES-128-CTR.Please note data is not encrypted using php-encrypt.I need to decrypt this data using openssl-decrypt().

I retrieve data from database as an array and pass this array onto foreach loop then pass each array value  as string to the above function as needed but still there is array to string conversion error.

Let me know if it is possible to use AES-128-CTR mode of encryption/decryption possible. Also why does this array to string conversion error occur and what is the solution?

```php
<?php

include "connect.php";

$query="select * from encrypted_data";

$rs=$dbhandle->query($query);

$key = hex2bin('2b7e151628aed2a6abf7157803cf5f3a');
$iv = hex2bin('f0f1f2f3f4f5f6f7f8f9fcfbf1fdfbfa');

while ($row = $rs->fetch_array()) {
  $data['encrypted_data'] = $row;

}

    foreach($data as $str)
    {

      $output = openssl_decrypt($str, 'AES-128-CTR', $key,OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
      echo $output;
    }


?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N8qz.png)

Comment: You've asked "why does this array to string conversion error occur", but you haven't included any error output (or any output at all) in your question. Could you [edit] to include the output you get, and what you were hoping for?

Comment: `var_dump($data)`, `var_dump($str)`, see what you're trying to work with!

Comment: Sure I will include the error output,also I tried var_dump but the issue is not resolved

Comment: `var_dump` does not resolve issues, it shows the content of a variable

Comment: Please see I have included a pic as link since I don't have reputation to embed image in the question

Comment: Yeah, we get it. *You are passing an array to `openssl_decrypt`.* It's an obvious mistake if you bothered to inspect the values you're trying to work with.

Comment: yes I saw the function definition then inside the foreach loop I passed $str instead of $data which is a string.But still having same problem

Comment: OK, let's cut to the end: replace `foreach($data as $str)` with `foreach($data['encrypted_data'] as $str)`

Comment: Using foreach($data['encrypted_data']. Error log is not appearing now!! But the data is not decrypted correctly.

Comment: @Constantin Even that is probably not correct, since then you're trying to decrypt all columns of one row. Not sure if that is what's desired here.

Comment: @Vidatha `$row` is an array! That makes `$data` a multi-dimensional array and `$str` an array! Debug. Your. Values!

Comment: Just some unknown characters are printed like this ;qh��U�Ώ��

Comment: @deceze $data['encrypted_data'] is single column of a given row

Comment: @deceze I was not trying to resolve the entire application or to change the architecture of his code, I would have given a complete answer for that, which I didn't. The idea is that, considering that he want to decrypt all the data (this is that `for`, right?), then it should use `$data['encrypted_data']` instead of `$data`

Comment: @VidathaKaruppan no, `$data['encrypted_data']` is an entire row

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `encrypted_data` (
  `time` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `dest` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `src` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `packetno` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `packetlength` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `encrypted_data` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: Above is the table schema for your ref

Comment: oh $data['encrypted_data'] returns entire row with the other column values also is it??

Comment: And what does this code of yours?! `$data['encrypted_data'] = $row;`

Comment: But please confirm me is it possible to use CTR mode of decryption/encryption in this case. As I no CTR modes available in the official PHP manual

Comment: I cannot do that, only you can. Run this `var_dump(openssl_get_cipher_methods());` on your server

Comment: I just copy pasted one of the encrypted string from database to see if the decryption happening correctly. But I did not get original text.

Comment: Run `var_dump(openssl_get_cipher_methods());` on your server, and tell us the result

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Thanks I will try that :)

Comment: Beside that, you have a design error in your code, you are trying to decrypt the entire row. See this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5315ff226ffc9689c2fbf9dc9e6a2a725f99ba50

Comment: I changed the query to 'select col_name from table_name' So only that column values are returned as array.

Comment: On using  this  var_dump(openssl_get_cipher_methods()); I am able to see aes-128-ctr is listed.

Comment: other than modifying the query  should there be any other correction?

Comment: Hi thanks to all for commenting

Comment: When I retrieve the encrypted string from db and pass it to the decrypting function.I observe the string with unknown characters is not the same.I compared the encrypted string obtained with online conversion as well as in the php program. Please note in both the algorithm was the same

Comment: But the hex format of the corresponding encrypted string remains the same.Please note that Iam using MYSQL database. I don't know how to store the data in HEX data type. Please let me how to store this data of hex data type inside MYSQL database